# Forgot vs have forgotten anniversary

Tags: present-perfect

My understanding of present perfect is basically something that has the possibility of happening more times,

> The author has written 3 books (he could write more books)
>
> The author wrote 3 books (he can't write more books because he died)

But with the verb forget I get a little confused sometimes.

Context: I just got home from work my wife prepared something for our anniversary but I didn't prepare anything because I forgot the anniversary, after realizing that what could I say to her?

I read a comment recently that says both of the following phrases are correct:

1. Sorry, I've forgotten our anniversary
2. Sorry, I forgot our anniversary

How could the present perfect be correct if, for me to talk about the anniversary in the present, I would have to remember it in the first place? Thus the forgetfulness is now completely in the past.

I get that there's a consequence on the present time by me forgetting the anniversary.

Are those two phrases correct and make sense in this context? In my head only 2 could make sense, but since I'm not a native speaker I cannot say that for sure.

Could this phrase be an option?

> Sorry, I forgot our anniversary and I haven't prepared anything but I can still fix this let's go to that restaurant you love.

Answer (score 0):

> My understanding of present perfect is basically something that has the possibility of happening more times,

This is an erroneous understanding: *"My father has died."* This is never going to happen again.

The present perfect appears in statements and questions that refer to the state of things at the moment **before** it is spoken:

"Have you cleaned your shoes?" / "You have cleaned your shoes."

> I read a comment recently that says both of the following phrases are correct:
>
> Sorry, I've forgotten our anniversary.
>
> Sorry, I forgot our anniversary.

They are, indeed both correct.

The main difference between the present perfect and the simple past is that the present perfect cannot accept a phrase or clause that expresses a definite time:

> *Sorry, I've forgotten our anniversary yesterday.
>
> Sorry, I forgot our anniversary yesterday.

Comment: To me "I've forgotten our anniversary" sounds a bit weird in this context. It could mean "I forgot when it was and I still don't remember", which doesn't make a lot of sense if you've subsequently been reminded or remembered.